# Crashlytics dSYM error

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

I've installed crashlytics on my mac and want to setup my project (xcode) with it. i create the run-script build phase by copying the code and the result of the first build is...

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Script-12ED173D1A96659F00DBC049.sh
    cd /Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App
    export ACTION=build
    export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
    export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
    export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export ALTERNATE_OWNER=danielbocksteger
    export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
    export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS=YES
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
    export ARCHS="armv7 arm64"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD="armv7 arm64"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT="armv7 arm64"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT=armv7
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT=arm64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT="armv7 arm64"
    export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS="armv7 arm64"
    export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=AppIcon
    export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS="iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
    export BUILD_COMPONENTS="headers build"
    export BUILD_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products
    export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products
    export BUILD_STYLE=
    export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
    export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/lk/ht709rc93ll2xdl3_sqlgkc80000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.3-6D520o/Xcode
    export CCHROOT=/var/folders/lk/ht709rc93ll2xdl3_sqlgkc80000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.3-6D520o/Xcode
    export CHMOD=/bin/chmod
    export CHOWN=/usr/sbin/chown
    export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu++0x
    export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
    export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=YES
    export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=YES
    export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation
    export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE=YES
    export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH=YES
    export CLASS_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/JavaClasses
    export CLEAN_PRECOMPS=YES
    export CLONE_HEADERS=NO
    export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app
    export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
    export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES
    export CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS=XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext
    export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer"
    export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=NO
    export COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES=NO
    export COMMAND_MODE=legacy
    export COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS=/var/folders/lk/ht709rc93ll2xdl3_sqlgkc80000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.3-6D520o/Xcode/CompositeSDKs
    export COMPRESS_PNG_FILES=YES
    export CONFIGURATION=Debug
    export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos
    export CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app
    export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA=NO
    export COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO
    export COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS=YES
    export CP=/bin/cp
    export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY=NO
    export CURRENT_ARCH=arm64
    export CURRENT_VARIANT=normal
    export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING=YES
    export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES
    export DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf
    export DEFAULT_COMPILER=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export DEFINES_MODULE=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=NO
    export DERIVED_FILES_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/DerivedSources
    export DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/DerivedSources
    export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/DerivedSources
    export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE=English
    export DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/English.lproj/Documentation
    export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM=NO
    export DSTROOT=/tmp/App.dst
    export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=App.app.dSYM
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO
    export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    export EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME=-iphoneos
    export EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO
    export EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME=embedded.mobileprovision
    export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND=YES
    export ENTITLEMENTS_ALLOWED=YES
    export ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED=YES
    export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS=".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES="*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    export EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/Executables
    export EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH=App.app
    export EXECUTABLE_NAME=App
    export EXECUTABLE_PATH=App.app/App
    export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=D2690A7437ECD701636BBD649B824BBEDCD47402
    export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME="iPhone Developer: Daniel Bocksteger (F2G86844MV)"
    export EXPANDED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE=6707cf02-9458-47df-8a22-ef98a90d3c3c
    export FILE_LIST=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects/LinkFileList
    export FIXED_FILES_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/FixedFiles
    export FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/Frameworks
    export FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX=-framework
    export FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "
    export FRAMEWORK_VERSION=A
    export FULL_PRODUCT_NAME=App.app
    export GCC3_VERSION=3.3
    export GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu99
    export GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=NO
    export GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN=YES
    export GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=0
    export GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS="c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    export GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="DEBUG=1 "
    export GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN=NO
    export GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT=YES
    export GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=NO
    export GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER=com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
    export GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE=YES_ERROR
    export GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE=YES
    export GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE=YES
    export GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export GID=20
    export GROUP=staff
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_FRAMEWORK_PREFIX_ENTRIES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_VFS=NO
    export HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include  /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include"
    export ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv
    export INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS=YES
    export INFOPLIST_FILE=App/Info.plist
    export INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
    export INFOPLIST_PATH=App.app/Info.plist
    export INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=NO
    export INFOSTRINGS_PATH=App.app/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
    export INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/App.dst/Applications
    export INSTALL_GROUP=staff
    export INSTALL_MODE_FLAG=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export INSTALL_OWNER=danielbocksteger
    export INSTALL_PATH=/Applications
    export INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/App.dst
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
    export JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS="-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
    export JAVA_APP_STUB=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES=YES
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE=JAR
    export JAVA_COMPILER=/usr/bin/javac
    export JAVA_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/Java
    export JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS=Resources
    export JAVA_JAR_FLAGS=cv
    export JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR=.
    export JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS=-urg
    export JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS="+E +OLDCSO"
    export KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS=NO
    export LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App_dependency_info.dat
    export LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE=NO
    export LD_MAP_FILE_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/App-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt
    export LD_NO_PIE=NO
    export LD_QUOTE_LINKER_ARGUMENTS_FOR_COMPILER_DRIVER=YES
    export LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS=" @executable_path/Frameworks"
    export LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    export LEX=lex
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE=YES
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX=-l
    export LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Extensions
    export LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "
    export LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES=NO
    export LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_arm64=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App.LinkFileList
    export LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_armv7=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/armv7/App.LinkFileList
    export LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
    export LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/English.lproj
    export LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export LOCAL_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer
    export LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/Library
    export MACH_O_TYPE=mh_execute
    export MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=14C109
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL=101002
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR=101000
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR=1002
    export MODULE_CACHE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
    export MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO=YES
    export NATIVE_ARCH=armv7
    export NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT=i386
    export NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT=x86_64
    export NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL=x86_64
    export NO_COMMON=YES
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal
    export OBJROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates
    export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
    export OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=0
    export OS=MACOS
    export OSAC=/usr/bin/osacompile
    export PACKAGE_TYPE=com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application
    export PASCAL_STRINGS=YES
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES="/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    export PBDEVELOPMENTPLIST_PATH=App.app/pbdevelopment.plist
    export PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS=objective-c
    export PKGINFO_FILE_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/PkgInfo
    export PKGINFO_PATH=App.app/PkgInfo
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Applications
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Tools
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
    export PLATFORM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
    export PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos
    export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH=arm64
    export PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=12F5027d
    export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
    export PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/PlugIns
    export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=YES
    export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/PrefixHeaders
    export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS=NO
    export PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/PrivateHeaders
    export PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME=App
    export PRODUCT_NAME=App
    export PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App/App/Info.plist
    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
    export PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export PROJECT=App
    export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/DerivedSources
    export PROJECT_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App
    export PROJECT_FILE_PATH=/Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App/App.xcodeproj
    export PROJECT_NAME=App
    export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build
    export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates
    export PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED=YES
    export PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/Headers
    export RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS=YES
    export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES=YES
    export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export RESOURCE_RULES_REQUIRED=YES
    export REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/ResourceManagerResources
    export REZ_OBJECTS_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
    export REZ_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "
    export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES=NO
    export SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/Scripts
    export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
    export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
    export SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
    export SDK_NAME=iphoneos8.3
    export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=12F5027d
    export SED=/usr/bin/sed
    export SEPARATE_STRIP=NO
    export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT=NO
    export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=YES
    export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=NO
    export SHALLOW_BUNDLE=YES
    export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DerivedSources
    export SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/SharedFrameworks
    export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
    export SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/SharedSupport
    export SKIP_INSTALL=NO
    export SOURCE_ROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App
    export SRCROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Documents/Entwicklung/App
    export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING=binary
    export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
    export STRIP_STYLE=all
    export SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES=1,2
    export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS="iphonesimulator iphoneos"
    export SYMROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products
    export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR=/System/Library/CoreServices
    export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR=/Applications/Extras
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
    export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
    export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1,2
    export TARGETNAME=App
    export TARGET_BUILD_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    export TARGET_NAME=App
    export TARGET_TEMP_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build
    export TEMP_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build
    export TEMP_FILES_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build
    export TEMP_FILE_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build
    export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
    export UID=501
    export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=App.app
    export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT=NO
    export USER=danielbocksteger
    export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Applications
    export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/danielbocksteger/Library
    export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=YES
    export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
    export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS=NO
    export VALIDATE_PRODUCT=NO
    export VALID_ARCHS="arm64 armv7 armv7s"
    export VERBOSE_PBXCP=NO
    export VERSIONPLIST_PATH=App.app/version.plist
    export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER=danielbocksteger
    export VERSION_INFO_FILE=App_vers.c
    export VERSION_INFO_STRING="\"@(#)PROGRAM:App  PROJECT:App-\""
    export WRAPPER_EXTENSION=app
    export WRAPPER_NAME=App.app
    export WRAPPER_SUFFIX=.app
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=6D520o
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=0630
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=0600
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=0630
    export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=App.app/XPCServices
    export YACC=yacc
    export arch=arm64
    export variant=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Script-12ED173D1A96659F00DBC049.sh

2015-02-19 19:42:53.142 run[2066:408725] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.11
2015-02-19 19:42:53.149 run[2066:408725] 

Crashlytics: dSYM Error

Unable to process App.app.dSYM at path /Users/danielbocksteger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-coxlexpwflomtfbpfumpipysjmtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app.dSYM
Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Crashlytics run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it.

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Can anybody explain what is not working here? How should i solve this issue?

I don't understand the problem and hadn't this some months ago.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to change "Debug Information Format" option in build settings of your target to "DWARF with dSYM file", located under  `Build Settings`>`Build Options`>`Debug Information Format`

Comment: If I change to "DWARF with dSYM file" I get a bunch of warnings. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. I have tried almost everything on SO but it's only thing that worked.

Comment: Awesome, this totally fixed it. For anyone struggling with this, it's located in Build Settings>Build Options>Debug Information Format.

Answer (score 7):

Goto build setting of your project then Search for debug information format in build setting then set "Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file"[image: Check below image to get clear idea]

Comment: This is exactly the same answer @Maxim Pavlov gave more than a year ago...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a Fabric in DEBUG mode you can just update a script to run it only on a specific configuration.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" 01c2d02bad8a3dbfd172897e1ea5cf89eb6b2306 7d515291891d5405f6bc1547c327dc3d08688d67f9057c269c25a11dcab83fee fi
```

Answer (score 1):

"DWARF with dSYM file" makes projects compile slower for DEBUG mode. So just embrace the warning for now :)

Comment: Why did i get negative points? Did i wrote something wrong? Can the people who gave me negative, explain pls?

Comment: I didn't give you the negative, but I think it's because Fabric asks for "DWARF with dSYM file" to be enabled for all configurations and you just said that @regetskcob should keep it disabled, without explaining this and that it may affect Fabric's behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Andre. In my work flow DEBUG mode is used only for local development and not reported to Fabric. So again in my case it is not a problem for DEBUG mode.

Comment: In your case there really isn't any reason to keep the flag enabled. However, in case someone needs Fabric to log crashs for DEBUG them just keeping the flag disabled would cause unwanted behavior! Since we don't know @regetskcob's case, we can't just say him to leave it off.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update here.

The `DWARF with dSYM file` flag is needed for **crashlytics** to log errors. If you're running locally, you probably don't need it to be active. Your project should even build a little faster if this is disabled.

So I would recommend you to only enabled it in case you need to log errors in **all** your configurations. Otherwise enable it only for those that will be used to generate your releases and live with the warnings (or find another way to disable it).