# Debug warning Xcode - dwarf-with-dsym?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, simulator

I get this warning upon compilation:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it. Unable to process FieldSense.app.dSYM at path /Users/dnb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ggomikgtclrabvaoqmbwhjyudhxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app.dSYM
```

How to solve?

Comment: similar and more than a year before this post's date :
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209582/make-sure-your-project-build-settings-are-generating-a-dsym-file-debug-informat
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614509/crashlytics-dsym-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. DEBUG\_INFORMATION\_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209582/make-sure-your-project-build-settings-are-generating-a-dsym-file-debug-informat)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To solve this issue:

1. Go to your project settings
2. Select your target
3. Go to Build settings
4. Scroll down to Debug Information Format (make sure to choose All settings)
5. Set the values to DWARF with dSYM File

[image]